# How to use byte-buddy to create delegated class that can modify method returned value?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Now there is an interface, I want to use byte buddy to create a delegated implementation.

For example, I have such an interface:

```java
public interface Foo {
    String foo();
}
```

And I want to dynamically create a class like this:

```java
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    private final Foo delegate;

    public FooImpl(Foo delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String foo() {
        return delegate.foo() + "_suffix";
    }
}
```

And I got this:

```java
Class<? extends Foo> clazz = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Foo.class, NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
    .defineField("delegate", Foo.class, PRIVATE | FINAL)
    .defineConstructor(PUBLIC)
    .withParameter(Foo.class)
    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(Object.class.getConstructor())
        .andThen(FieldAccessor.ofField("delegate").setsArgumentAt(0)))
    .method(ElementMatchers.isDeclaredBy(Foo.class)
        .and(ElementMatchers.returns(String.class)))
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.toField("delegate"))
    .make()
    .load(Foo.class.getClassLoader())
    .getLoaded();
```

But I don't know how to modify the method delegation's returned value.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you want to delegate to `Foo` directly. Rather, implement a seperate delegation class where one of the parameters is annotated by `@FieldValue("delegate")` and then invoke the method in question where you return the transfromed value. This value is then returned from the interception method which represents the method that is returned by the proxy. E.g.:

```
public class MyDelegator {
  public static String intercept(@FieldValue("delegate") Foo delegate) {
    return delegate.foo() + "_suffix"
  }
}
```